# frequency characterritic of activ high pass filter

Tags: signal-analysis

How can i see  the characteristic(frequency response) of  an active high pass filter?I attached  the circuit and the value of resitence .Can i see it on the computer without an osciloscope ?How can i calculate it on the paper?
Thank you very much!

[image: Active high pass filter]

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for electronics.se. You can see the response on the computer using a circuit simulator such as Spice (personally I use Multisim).

Comment: To **calculate** it on the paper, you need a basic **circuit theory** knowledge. To **simulate** it on a computer, you need an *electronics simulator** program and to **observe** the real phyiscal electrical output on your PC, you either need a **capturing** device or you can use **audio** card for a very simple PC audio oscilloscope software. In any case you better ask it on another place like electronics.se as MBaz said...

Answer (score 1):

There are many online calculators with plot etc. options you could use. An example: http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/Fkeisan.htm